# Change ContextMenu Font Size in C#

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu, font-size

Is it possible to change the font size used in a ContextMenu using the .NET Framework 3.5 and C# for a desktop application?  It seems it's a system-wide setting, but I would like to change it only within my application.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are defining your own context menu via a `ContextMenuStrip` in Windows Forms, use the *Font* property.

If you are defining your own context menu via a `ContextMenu` in WPF, use the various *Fontxxx* properties such as *FontFamily* and *FontSize*.

You cannot change the default context menus that come with controls; those are determined by system settings.  So if you want the "Copy/Cut/Paste/etc." menu with a custom font size for a WinForms `TextBox`, you'll have to create a `ContextMenuStrip` with the appropriate font size and assign it to the `TextBox`'s *ContextMenuStrip* property.

Answer (score 3):

In WPF:

```
<Window.ContextMenu FontSize="36">
    <!-- ... -->
</Window.ContextMenu
```

In WinForms:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 24F);
```

Comment: he's talkin abt contextmenu, not strip

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font size of a System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip.

If you need to change the font size of the default Cut/Copy/Paste context menu on text boxes I guess you need to set the ContextMenu property to a custom menu that replaces the default menu.

Answer (score 0):

You mention .NET 3.5 - are you writing in WPF? If so, you can specify font size for the TextBlock.FontSize attached property

```
<Whatever.ContextMenu TextBlock.FontSize="12">
  <MenuItem ... /> <!-- Will get the font size from parent -->
</Whatever.ContextMenu>
```

Or, you could specify it in a style that affects all menu items

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
   <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

Of course, it's always better to let the system setting determine the font size. Some people may have changed it to better fit their physical condition (like poor eye sight) or hardware (big/small screen). Whatever you force in your code will be the wrong choice for some people, while you give them no way to change it.